# Uistepper in Uialertview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

How can I show `UIStepper` in `UIAlertView`? Also suggest me any other alternative to show `UIStepper` in pop-up.

Comment: UIAlertView itself an UIView so you can add any Control to UIAlertView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way of inserting views in `UIAlertView` would be to add them as a subview

Try the following

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n" delegate:nil  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    UIStepper* stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] init];
    stepper.frame = CGRectMake(12.0, 5.0, 100, 10);
    [alert addSubview:stepper];
    [alert show];
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.. Hope it will help you

```
 UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 20, 0, 0)];

    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]init];// you can set your frame according to ypur requirment
    [alert addSubview:stepper];
    [alert show];
```