# How to add a UIStepper to AlertView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistepper

I want to add a UIStepper to my alerView but the stepper is not showing here is my code

```
 var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Hello works", message: "\n\n", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
 var stepper = UIStepper()
    stepper.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(12.0), y: CGFloat(5.0), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(10))
    alert.addSubview(stepper)
    alert.show()
```

Comment: Here is an example that works, but it is in objective c :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869020/uistepper-in-uialertview Maybe it helps you anyway.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Can you post your change to swift code? What error says?

Comment: This is the change and it did not give any error just not showing up in the alert view

Comment: Cant see the change, anyway, Try moving this values:
    stepper.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(12.0), y: CGFloat(5.0), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(10))
Maybe you are drawing it of the alert.

Comment: That did not work

Comment: I believe the subview needs to be added to the titleView of the alertView

Comment: 1. UIAlertView has been deprecated for a while now. 2. It does not support adding custom views.

Comment: How can i add the view to titleView? @Joakim

Comment: @rmaddy What can i use for a pop up with UIStepper in it?

Comment: You need to create your own custom alert or find a 3rd party alert that allows custom views to be added.

Comment: Check the following answer, it should solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32790860/3726570

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated. You should use `UIAlertController` instead. Here is an answer that explains how you can implement what you want using a UIAlertController:

[UIAlertController - add custom views to actionsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790207/uialertcontroller-add-custom-views-to-actionsheet/32790860#32790860)

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Below is code for implementing UIAlertView Using UIAlertController in swift and add your custom views on it .


        let logoutAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "DemoAlert", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)



        logoutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))



        logoutAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            // Write your code here

        }))

        var stepper = UIStepper()
        stepper.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(12.0), y: CGFloat(5.0), width: CGFloat(100), height: CGFloat(10))

        // You can add any view on UIAlert controller using below code:

        logoutAlert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = stepper.frame

        logoutAlert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = stepper


        self.present(logoutAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```